# Calculated measure that combines two values to form a fractional value [Analysis Services]

Tags: olap, mdx, ssas

In my cube I have two measure: A that stores values of the form *aaaaa* and B that stores values like *bbbbb*. I want to define measure C that will give the values *aaaaa.bbbbb*. How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you provide a quick example?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, you could do something like this:

```
with member [Measures].[A] as 123
member [Measures].[B] as 456
member [Measures].[C] as val(cstr([Measures].[A]) + "." + cstr([Measures].[B]))

select {[Measures].[A], [Measures].[B], [Measures].[C]} on 0
from [YourCube]
```